# Why is the textfeld not enlarging on the JFrame?

Tags: java

Below is a Java program which does not work properly. I wanted the JTextfield to go to the bottom, and be 50x50, but it is not working. I was wondering if I could get some help.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class Main {

    public static JTextField intext = new JTextField();

    public static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    public static boolean running = true;
    public static   String runtext;
    public static String word = "HELLO";
    public static String guesses = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        intext.setBounds(5,667,50,50);
        panel.add(intext);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hangman");
        frame.setBounds(10,10,600,750);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setResizable(false);

        frame.setVisible(true);
```

I inferred that when using the .setBounds() method the JTextfield  would go where it was needed, though it remains at the top, and extremely thin.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include the end brackets!

Comment: frame.setLayout(null);

Comment: Depending on where I put the line, it either had no effect on the output or got rid of the textfield completely. Thanks for your time, though,

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your code this way:-

```
panel.setLayout(null); // setting layout for panel
panel.setBounds(0,0,600,650); // setting bounds for panel with respect to frame

intext.setBounds(5,557,50,50); //setting bounds for textfield with respect to panel

panel.add(intext);   

JFrame frame= new JFrame("Hangman");  
frame.setBounds(10,10,600,750); 

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

frame.add(panel);

frame.setResizable(false);

frame.setLayout(null); // setting layout for frame

frame.setVisible(true);
```

Make sure to include layouts for your components and set the bounds for your JPanel's and JTextField's properly.